# SQS does not receive messages posted through SNS

Tags: ruby, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a simple scenario of publish a message to a SNS topic, which is subscribed by a SQS queue, but somehow the queue never receives the messages (i.e., not show up in the SQS console). Here are the codes in Ruby:

```
sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new;
sqs = Aws::SQS::Client.new;
q1 = sqs.create_queue({queue_name: "queue1”});
t1 = sns.create_topic({name: "topic1"});
q1_attr = sqs.get_queue_attributes({queue_url: q1.queue_url,attribute_names: ["All"]});
s1 = sns.subscribe({topic_arn: t1.topic_arn, protocol: "sqs", endpoint: q1_attr.attributes['QueueArn']});
resp = sns.publish({topic_arn: t1.topic_arn, message: "Test message"});
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: You haven't confirmed the subscription

Comment: Fred: which subscription? I don't see any

Comment: After subscribing the queue to the topic (penultimate line) you need to confirm the subscription

Answer (score 1):

The second quote in this line:

```
q1 = sqs.create_queue({queue_name: "queue1”});
```

is a 'fancy' quote `”` instead of `"`. Change it to this:

```
q1 = sqs.create_queue({queue_name: "queue1"});
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I fixed that in my test, but somehow it got in the posting here. So it is not the issue.

Comment: I've resolved the issue and make the scenario works! What is missing is after subscribing to the topic, I need to set the Policy for queue to allow it to receive the messages published to the SNS topic.